# Drupal Curl, $GET

Tags: post, drupal, curl, get

I am creating a Drupal 7 node from remote.  In my server I have a script that uses

```
now=$(date)
curl --data "date=$now" http://website.com
```

That is supposed to send the value of $now to the url.  In my remote nodecreate.php form I am using

```
$node->field_date[$node->language][0]['value'] = $_GET['date'];
```

To set the value of the date field in the node.  Problem is that the node is created successfully, but the date is blank.

I have tried other variations such as setting a value to a string in the remote nodecreate.php like this

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
$node->field_date[$node->language][0]['value'] = $date;
```

however that did not work either.  Anyone got ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the following :

```
$node->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $date;
```

I suppose here that you are using translation on node but not translatable fields.

Comment: As i stated above that line of code does not work, so either the curl statement is incorrect or the $_GET is incorrect.

Comment: This is not the same line! "LANGUAGE_NONE" is use in mine. If you don't set the variable with the correct key it can explain why it goes wrong ...